# How many tickets open at the end of the week?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hopefully someone can help me further with this.

I am writing a query to extract open ticket information per week. An open ticket is classed as a ticketID that has a solvedate as NULL.

I want to show this data by week commencing date (monday to friday) so all tickets that haven't been solved by 5pm Friday would be counted for that week. An output would look like this.

```
week commencing | open tickets
05-jan-2018     |     5
12-jan-2018     |     6
```

I would need this to go back at least 12 months (52 weeks)

What would be the best way of achieving this? I have a calendar table with the date, week commencing date stored I am just unsure about getting it to do the above.

So far I just have the following clause in my select statement CASE WHEN Solvedate is null or solvedate > @LastWorkDay then 1 else 0 The LastWorkDay parameter is set for last friday, so this works and shows me all open tickets from last week. However I am just not too sure how I would go about getting this data for the past 52 weeks

Many thanks

Comment: "I am writing a query ...".  Where's your query???  I don't see it.

Comment: So far I just have the following clause in my select statement
CASE WHEN Solvedate is null or solvedate > @LastWorkDay then 1 else 0

The LastWorkDay parameter is set for last friday, so this works and shows me all open tickets from last week. However I am just not too sure how I would go about getting this data for the past 52 weeks..

Comment: Don't put your query in comment section.  Modify your original post, and put it there.  No one is going to read that.

Comment: Nothing we can do if that's all you give.  Please post table structure, sample input, expected output, and your query.  Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I think this does what you need.  It is designed to run for one calendar year (you pick what year by changing the value for **@vYear**).

```
DECLARE 
    @vYear AS INT,
    @vJan1Year DATETIME,
    @vDec31Year DATETIME
/*  Set the @vYear variable to the year you are analyzing   */
SET
    @vYear = 2018
SET 
    @vJan1Year = DATEADD(yyyy, @vYear - 1900, 0)
SET
    @vDec31Year = DATEADD(yyyy, @vYear - 1899, 0)
; WITH 
    cte_Fridays AS 
    (
    SELECT 
        @vJan1Year AS DateOfYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte_Fridays.DateOfYear)
    FROM 
        cte_Fridays
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(d,1,cte_Fridays.DateOfYear) < @vDec31Year
    )
SELECT 
    cte_Fridays.DateOfYear,
    COUNT(t.[ticketID])
FROM
    cte_Fridays
LEFT JOIN
    yourtablename AS t
ON
    (t.[solvedate] IS NULL OR  t.[solvedate] > cte_Fridays.DateOfYear)
AND
    t.[opendate] < cte_Fridays.DateOfYear
WHERE 
    DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 0 ,cte_Fridays.DateOfYear)) = 'Friday'
GROUP BY 
    cte_Fridays.DateOfYear
ORDER BY 
    DateOfYear
OPTION 
    (MaxRecursion 366)
```